# Linear regression model, field missing in test set

Tags: r, regression, linear-model

I am currently trying to solve a Kaggle Competition (Rossmann Store Sales). 
My linear regression model consists of all fields in the dataset. The objective is to predict sales.

List of all variables: [rossmann-store-sales](https://www.kaggle.com/c/rossmann-store-sales/data)

```
ctrl <- trainControl(method = "cv",number = 10)
mod1 <- train(Sales ~ . - Date ,data = train,method = "lm",
              trControl = ctrl, metric="Rsquared")
summary(mod1)
mod1
```

In the training set, the data contains a Field called `Customers` and it is missing in the testing set.

My predict function fails since it encounters a missing field (`Customers`) in my testing set.

```
pred <- predict(mod1,newdata = test)
```

How to handle such a case or is it, that this field is suppose to help me in feature engineering?

Please let me know if any further information is required.